# What order do the datasource methods get called for UITableView after reloadData?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5

From what I can tell from my call stack, a call to 'reloadData' calls 'tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:' immediately afterwards on the same call stack, yet, calls to 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' get called on the runloop sometime after.

This seems odd to me because if a variable which reflects the true number of rows for the table view exists, let's call it 'numberOfRows', is returned in 'tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:' but a call immediately after 'reloadData' changes the value of 'numberOfRows' then we arrive at an inconsistent state for 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'. More or less calls to 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' will occur than there are 'numberOfRows'.

I believe this exact problem is causing me a crash. I've always made the assumption that datasource calls occur in well thought out order queued one after another on the main runloop to avoid these kinds of errors.

Were my assumptions incorrect?

(iOS 5.1 simulator, untested on 6+)

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you change the "true number of rows" then you have to call reloadData again (or bracket the changes in beginUpdates - insertRows... - deleteRows... - endUpdates).

Comment: #1: don't make assumptions about the order in which these calls are going to be made... because Apple might change it!  #2: don't call reloadData until you have all of your data ready.  If you implement the data source and delegate methods correctly there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Martin: The documentation doesn't explicitly state (as far as I can tell) whether or not multiple calls to 'reloadData' will multiply the calls to 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' so making these extra calls (since I don't know when the data may change) seemed wasteful. Without diving too deep into what I'm doing, there really wasn't a need to reloadData at the point the data was read. My tableView was autoreleased, popped off the navigation stack, and expected to be destroyed. If 'tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:' and calls to 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' were queued one after...

Comment: another in order then it wouldn't matter what data existed at this point anyway. The calls would resolve correctly and then the tableView would be destroyed.

Luckily, from my testing, it appears that multiple calls to 'reloadData' don't necessarily multiply calls to 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'.

Comment: Nicholas: Great answer. I'd up vote you if if I had the cred.

One thing to note however, it must be true that 'tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:' is called explicitly sometime before the calls to 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' or the tableView would always end up in an inconsistent state. But how long that sometime is, is completely up to Apple (like you stated :)).